I want to design a ultra stable low noise current source for a generalized application
Which technology nodes have the best low noise output comparing the technology and to find out the best possible architecture and topology which fits both consideration?
Some technology comparison between CMOS, FDSOI, SiGe, FINFET?

Anything with a PN junction in it will have shot noise. That's a given and it adds to other noise sources. You can work to avoid PN junctions to get rid of that source. But this means an entirely different design approach. You should write a lot more about what you need (exact current source values) and why you need it (or them.)

Your requirements are extremely vague. Are you looking to create a “better LM334”? “General purpose” may mean different things, based on the context. Do you want to design a discrete analog IC, or an analog cell, or… Please edit your question to clarify and then flag this comment as “no longer needed”.

Digital or analog noise? What frequency region?

Typically an analog process is specialized so it does not reuse a digital process node, if that’s what you are implying.
There are many analog cells that are designed for mainstream mixed-purpose CMOS processes. Those are optimized to perform the best on a given process, and typically are optimized for area since that drives the cost. There’s quite a difference between area-optimized and noise-optimized cells. Fewer of the latter are available.
All modern low-noise non-RF analog parts like high bit ADCs are made on an analog CMOS process, usually proprietary to the manufacturer.
